# Infinite loop replacing blanks with text

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The sequence of tasks is correct but does not go to completion.

I think that the problem arises at some point after this line

```
    LastRow = .Range("G9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Determine Last Row in Table`

    For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
```

but I am not sure what is wrong with it.

```vb
    Option Explicit

    Sub CreateWordDocuments()
    Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow As Long
    Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
    Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
    Dim WordContent As Word.Range
    With Sheet1

        If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
            MsgBox "Please select a template from the drop down list"
            .Range("F3").Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
        TemplName = .Range("F3").Value 'Set Template Name
        DocLoc = Sheet9.Range("F" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Document Filename

        'Open Word Template
        On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
        Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'Launch a new instance of Word
            Err.Clear
            'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
            Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'launches word application
            WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
        End If

        LastRow = .Range("G9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Determine Last Row in Table

        For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
            Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
            TagName = .Cells(CustRow, 7).Value 'Tag Name
            TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, 8).Value 'Tag Value
            With WordDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = TagName
                .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
            End With
        Next CustRow

        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("H8").Value & "_" & ".docx"
        WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
        WordDoc.Close
        WordApp.Quit

    End With
    End Sub
```

The sequence I would like;

1. Open the template I made with the blanks that need to be filled is opened
2. Then the all blanks are replaced with the required text
3. the document saves as another name so the template is unchanged
4. then I can just go into the folder and open up the new word document to make any further changes

Comment: Reset the error handling so it doesn't resume next: use "On Error GoTo 0" after the WordApp "If" procedure. Use a break point within your loop (right-click the For Custrow line); then use F5 to advance your loop one iteration at a time. Check that your loop is actually progressing as planned. It might be the case that it's not an infinite loop, but just very slow?

Comment: no error in lastrow calculating, but you didn't say what you want to get with your macro

Comment: Hi Chris, I have done what you suggested, however, I have the same result, all of the blanks have been filled but it is still doing something in the background.

Comment: On a side note I have text that needed to be exchanged in the header but it has not changed, would you by any chance know why?

Comment: Hi Patel, I edited the post to give you a step by step of what I am aiming for

Comment: If you step through manually with F8, what does the loop look like?  Also, you seem to be mixing Early-binding with Late-binding?

Comment: Why do you `Open` the document *inside* the `For` loop, but `Close` it *outside* the loop?  You will only `Save` and `Close` the *last* document, not all of them, and might run out of Memory (depending on how many Word Documents it opens!)  Does it work if you move `Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template` to **before** `For CustRow = 8 To LastRow`?

Comment: Hi Chronocidal, That Worked! Although I still have an issue in that the text in the header does not get chnaged, any ideas on that front?

Comment: Probably a bit late now...  But is there a reason *why* you're not just using [Mail Merge](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3) to do this with less hassle?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue that you have is not an Infinite Loop, it is a Memory Leak, which occurs here:

```
For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template

    <snip>

Next CustRow

FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("H8").Value & "_" & ".docx"
WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
WordDoc.Close
```

Basically, you open a new copy of the workbook for *every* instance of the loop.  if `LastRow = 18`, then you are Opening 10 copies of the workbook, then save and close the **last** one.  If `LastRow = 1008`, then your computer probably crashes.  (This also means that each replacement is only made on one Document!)

To fix this, just move the `Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template` line to before the `For` loop.  That way, you open 1 copy of the template, make *all* of your replacements in it, and then save it again.

The *second* issue is that `Document.Content.Find` **does not search the Header** (or Footer), just the main text body.  You will need to look in `Document.Section.Header.Range.Text` to sort that out.  Full code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWordDocuments()
    'Putting "As <Type>" at the end ONLY sets the Type of the last Variable.  Everything else is Variant
    Dim CustRow As Long, CustCol As Long, LastRow As Long, TemplRow As Long
    Dim DocLoc As String, TagName As String, TagValue As String, TemplName As String, FileName As String
    Dim WordDoc As Object, WordApp As Object
    'WordContent is not used

    With Sheet1
        If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
            MsgBox "Please select a template from the drop down list"
            .Range("F3").Select
            Exit Sub
        End If

        TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
        TemplName = .Range("F3").Value 'Set Template Name
        DocLoc = Sheet9.Range("F" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Document Filename

        'Open Word Template
        On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
        Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'Launch a new instance of Word
            Err.Clear
            'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
            Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'launches word application
            WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 'Let us know if there are any errors after this!


        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row 'Determine Last Row in Table

        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template ONCE

        For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
            TagName = .Cells(CustRow, 7).Value 'Tag Name
            TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, 8).Value 'Tag Value

            'Replace in Body
            With WordDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = TagName
                .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
            End With

            'Replace in Header
            With WordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
                .Text = Replace(.Text, TagName, TagValue)
            End With

            'Replace in Footer
            With WordDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
                .Text = Replace(.Text, TagName, TagValue)
            End With

        Next CustRow

        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("H8").Value & "_" & ".docx"
        WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
        WordDoc.Close
        WordApp.Quit

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution! I am however experiencing an issue. I added the header and footer peices of code to the spreadsheet but when I run the code it creates hundreds of pages in the document. The original formatting that I had in the header has dissappeared and only the text that was replaced is left, this text is the only text that is on the page, and the code does not come to an end.

Comment: @CalumBurns What is `LastRow` at that point?  As I suggested earlier in a comment, try stepping through line-by-line with F8.  Does it work if you comment out just the Header/Footer code?